# Send Email with close_spider with Scrapy (Python on Windows)

Tags: email, smtp, scrapy

i want to send a "spider complete" email when scrapy are done. First i tried the python mail functions, but is doesnt work for me. Now i try the scrapy email classes. But it wont send the emails.

Here is my code:

```
def send_email(self, recipient, message, title):

    from scrapy.mail import MailSender

    mailer = MailSender( 'smtp.gmail.com', 'mail@domain.de', 'mymail@gmail.com', 'mypassword', 587 )
    mailer.send(to=["myemail@domain.com"], subject="My Subject", body="This a test")
```

There is no error message or something, it doenst work - i dont no what are the problem is. Maybe there is a problem with my system? (Work on windows 8)

I dont think so, because the smtp Settings are using google services, not my local system.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your post you say that you are using scrapy on windows:

You have installed pywin32 and pyssl? You need to install on windows!

Do a simple test to see if scrapy is work correctly:

```
scrapy shell <some_url>
```

And see if you don't have error or warning messages

Comment: Yes, Scrapy works perfect. Only the mail functions dont work.